# behat / mink: using phpunit mock in context

Tags: mocking, phpunit, behat, mink

I cannot find a way to use a phpunit mock in a behat context.

My FeatureContext cannot extend `PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase` because it already extends `MinkContext`.

I tried to have it implement `PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_MockObject` but I got the fatal error that it should implement the 5 abstract methods.

I tried with the static call to `PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase` inside a FeatureContext method (where I need the mock) but then I got this error `Non-static method PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase::getMockBuilder() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in features/bootstrap/FeatureContext.php`.

Any idea how I could achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is [another question where it looks like it's explained what you need](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28566717/is-it-possible-to-create-a-mock-outside-a-test-case-in-phpunit).

For mocking dependencies for Behat I prefer using Mockery. It's an independent library so the usage is the same from PHPUnit or Behat.

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't find that one. I ended up creating an instance of the Mock Generator as suggested by [paul.ago's comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28566717/is-it-possible-to-create-a-mock-outside-a-test-case-in-phpunit#comment56606334_28600731) (ie. `$mockGen = new \PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_Generator(); $mock = $mockGen->getMock($originalClassName, $methods);`) and I called  the methods I needed  (`once()`) statically using `\PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase` as [explained in the chosen answer of the question you mentioned](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28600731/5794148)